# Does Hardened Scales trigger when +1/+1 counter are moved from one permanent to another?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If a +1/+1 counter get's moved from one creature to another does [Hardened Scales](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Hardened%20Scales) double the amount of counters that the second creature gets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, Hardened Scales triggers off moving +1/+1 counters. From the official rules:

> 121.5. **If an effect says to “move” a counter, it means to take that counter from the object it’s currently on and put it onto a second object.** If the first and second objects are the same object, nothing happens. If the first object has no counters, nothing happens; the second object doesn’t get a counter put on it. If the second object (or any possible second objects) is no longer in the correct zone when the effect would move the counter, nothing happens; a counter isn’t removed from the first object.

Note that Hardened Scales only triggers **once** per batch of counters moved, so if several counters are moved at once, it will not double the amount, but only add 1.